# Reasonable rate limiting settings with PF firewall

Tags: firewall, rate-limiting, pf

I have the following settings in my pf.conf to dissuade abusive clients (I get a few a day that are obviously just scraping content indiscriminately and slow everything down):

```
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to { $loadbalancer1_int } port $web_ports flags S/SA keep state (max-src-conn 80, max-src-conn-rate 200/5, overload <web_flood> flush)
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to { $loadbalancer2_int } port $web_ports flags S/SA keep state (max-src-conn 80, max-src-conn-rate 200/5, overload <web_flood> flush)
```

Unfortunately some of my customers are getting themselves blocked.  I don't know what these customers are doing to trigger such network IO.  I keep upping the values and they keep getting themselves blocked.  Aren't these values (80 connections & 200 connections within 5 seconds) well within what would generally be considered "abusive"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"abusive" is entirely relative, but in terms of web access setting a rate limit on number of connections/second is almost certain to catch legitimate users.

Bear in mind what happens when you visit a web page

1. A HTTP connection is opened and the main page (let's say `index.html`) is downloaded.
2. Your browser parses `index.html` and figures out what other resources it needs:

   - CSS
   - Javascript
   - Images
   - Stuff in a  or  (more "main pages")
   - Probably more stuff I'm forgetting
3. Your browser grabs all of those items.
   It can do this one of two ways"

   - Serially: Downloading each item in sequence (one connection at a time)
   - In parallel: Downloading several items at once (multiple open connections).

HTTP keepalive theoretically keeps the number of connect() cycles down, but some browsers may not support HTTP keepalive (or may decide not to use it for whatever reason), in which case every item being downloaded means another connection gets opened to the server.

One web page is therefore potentially a huge number of connections - easily enough to trip your firewall, especially if you have more than one user on an IP or your users browse actively.

---

Rather than blanket blocking you have a couple of choices:

1. **Tag matching packets in `pf` and bandwidth-limit them with `altq`.**
   This isn't really ideal - you're still going to catch legit users - but at least they're throttled (slow), not blocked (broken).
2. **Use [mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442), [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org) or similar**
   These modules are more work for Apache, but are more configurable and will help you avoid catching legit users.

Comment: Good insights.  I appreciate your alternatives, as well.  I suppose I'll have to forgo the limiting for now.

Comment: @myferalprofessor If you're really having trouble with web scrapers `mod_evasive` is probably your best option.  Doing throttling right (slowing down as requests pour in, then speeding back up after idle time) is a lot of work, and `pf` isn't really up to the task (it's outside it's design scope).